# How to share kernel objects, such as Waitable Timers, between processes?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-kernel

I am creating an object, for example a Waitable Timer, and I want to share my object with another process:

```cpp
// In process 1:
HANDLE hTimerProcess1 = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, L"Time1");
// In process 2:
HANDLE hTimerProcess2 = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, L"Time1");
```

1. As the third parameter, I am passing the same name `"Time1"`, does that mean that I am creating a new kernel object `hTimerProcess2` but with the same descriptor table entry as `hTimerProcess1`, or is `hTimerProcess2` just a reference to the existing object (`hTimerProcess1`)?
2. How can I prove that `hTimerProcess1` and `hTimerProcess2` are the same kernel object? I tried getting their address but they are different.

I'm reading M. Richter's "Advanced Win32 Programming"

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you know there's a more recent edition of that book? Windows Via C/C++

Comment: i am reading 4th edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs to `CreateWaitableTimer`:

> If the named timer object exists before the function call, the
>   function returns a handle to the existing object and GetLastError
>   returns **ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS**.

So the answer to your question #1 is no, you're not creating a new kernel object - if both calls succeed, they'll refer to the same timer.

How to prove they're the same? You could probably do this by calling `SetWaitableTimer` in one process, and waiting on it in the other.

If you want to make extra sure that you get the same timer object in the second process, call `OpenWaitableTimer` instead - since this only succeeds if the timer already exists.

Comment: how properly call SetWaitableTimer function in another process?

Comment: @OlexanderHaliy Call it on the handle you get back from CreateWaitableTimer in that process. Each process will have a unique handle, but the handles refer to the same kernel object.

Comment: ok i  understood that the handles are different but they are refering to the same object, so if i pass a handle to the SetWaitableTimer i will activate timer but how i can use it on another to proof that they are the same

Comment: beside is it possible to get the number of active processes using the same kernel object?

Comment: Process #1 waits for the timer to go off using `WaitForSingleObject`, process #2 triggers the timer using `SetWaitableTimer`. Process #1 will only wake up if the timer has gone off, and process #2 is the only process to trigger it, therefore they're the same timer.

Comment: @OlexanderHaliy You can use [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx) to browse named objects.  Right-click and select "Properties" to see how many handles they have.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of [CreateWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this is possible:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the timer object. If the named timer object exists before the function call, the function returns a handle to the existing object and GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS.

So you should check the value (not the address) of the handles and the result of `GetLastError()` to see if your implementation succeeds.